# Asking about old russian amplifier internal circuit

Tags: amplifier, analog, photodiode

I worked with an old russian machine in my lab, which contains an input from a photodiode with amplification circuit.

The amplification is composed into 2 stages , the first with a JFET transistor and the other with an amplifier IC (123ун1б) where the internal circuit in the figure below :

[image: 123YH1b]

In the datasheet the only interesting Information that the gain is between 100 and 350 , and nothing either.

The amplifier ic with external components are showed in this figure :

[image: circuit]

where the correction capacitor is 120 pF, the resistor between 4 and 5 is 3.9K
and the load resistor is 5.1K

My goal is to know how we can choose the gain of this circuit which given approximetly 100??
what are the value that should be changed?
What are your opinion and what's the way to know the solution ?

Comment: Ask the old Russian? OR adjust R16.

Comment: Or build it in a simulator and play with it.

Comment: Is there an optical chopper of some kind prior to the detector diode?

Comment: @Trevor :adjusting R16 is a good way to play with gain not understand how it work, and about the simulation , I tried the LTspice but how to understand the current gain in the circuit!

Comment: @jonk yes, it's an encoder I think

Comment: @EvaGhanoume It's hard to know what to suggest if you don't even know what it is doing. Is this an optical fiber communications device? An optical chopper? Etc. One thing for sure, \$C_4\$ and \$C_1\$ strongly suggests AC of some kind. A JFET is a good way to go for sensitive detection with diode detectors. But my experience with those is DC, not AC. \$T_6\$ and \$T_7\$ are a current mirror (part of which, too, is also the 3-emitter device at the right side.) But you've been circumspect about what this does and I'm not so interested in spending time working it out on my own.

Comment: @jonk , the signal from the photodiode is a square wave output, like the signal from the encoder with a frequency to 10khz.
so we said that it's a optical chopper.
I know the work pre-amplifier of jfet, and my question inside the IC, what you said about the current mirror is very important but I want to know more about the other transistor with the feedback idea , can you help me?
and sorry for spending your time, my goal is to understand this integrated circuit

Comment: @EvaGhanoume Start with \$T_7\$. It's diode-connected. A reason for this may be to get access to the fact that its \$V_{BE}\$ varies with temperature. Coupled with \$R_{10}\$, means that these two will create a somewhat thermally dependent (and supply rail dependent) current in diode-connected \$T_7\$. This will mirror over to \$T_6\$, which pulls this "programmed" current through \$R_9\$ (or also through pin 6 or pin 2, via resistor \$R_8\$.) That's a start. What is \$T_4\$ to you and how does \$R_9\$ relate to the effect on pin 6, for example? Can you say? If not, perhaps I'd waste my time.